# Idiom for when you're bad at something

Tags: idioms

What are some idioms for when you're bad at something?

Like:
I can't (do something) to save my life.

But aside from that what are other idioms. Maybe something similar to the one above.

Comment: The idiomatic usage that's taken the English-speaking world by storm in recent decades is *I **suck** [at that]*. But this is essentially an Off Topic "list" question.

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for-toffee